# How to use jQuery tabs to link to a URL rather than load a tab using Html.ActionLink?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test")</li>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...follow_a_tab.27s_URL_instead_of_loading_its_content_via_ajax) you can learn how to use the `select` callback for that.

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
        if( url ) {
            location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: When clicked through to the url, the tab is not selected with the method.

Comment: Well, I think that is intended. Why should the tab be selected if you call another page you are about to leave it in this moment? Is the tab on the page you link to also existent? Then you have to select it on load.